# Removing cached reference to missing table: services_user?

Tags: 7, users, caching, services, javascript

When trying to update user profiles via the Services module (not via drupal) - calling mysite.com/drupalgap/user/1.json as a POST with correct parameters -  I'm getting the following error:

> 500 Internal Server Error :  An error occurred (42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]:  Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydbname.services_user' doesn't exist

I've cleared all my caches but the problem persists. In fact, the `cache` table rebuilds itself with the a serialized reference to a `services_user` table in `schema` row. The line is huge, but here's the part with that reference:

```
s:13:"services_user";a:3:{s:6:"fields";a:3:{s:3:"uid";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:3:"int";s:8:"unsigned";b:1;s:8:"not null";b:1;}s:7:"created";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:3:"int";s:8:"not null";b:1;s:7:"default";i:0;}s:7:"changed";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:3:"int";s:8:"not null";b:1;s:7:"default";i:0;}}s:6:"module";s:8:"services";s:4:"name";s:13:"services_user";}s:8:"smart_ip";a:5:{s:6:"fields";a:8:{s:8:"geoip_id";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:3:"int";s:4:"size";s:3:"big";s:8:"not null";b:1;}s:6:"ip_ref";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:3:"int";s:4:"size";s:3:"big";s:8:"not null";b:1;}s:12:"country_code";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:7:"varchar";s:6:"length";i:3;s:8:"not null";b:1;}s:6:"region";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:7:"varchar";s:6:"length";i:3;s:8:"not null";b:0;}s:4:"city";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:7:"varchar";s:6:"length";i:128;s:8:"not null";b:0;}s:3:"zip";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:7:"varchar";s:6:"length";i:8;s:8:"not null";b:0;}s:8:"latitude";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:5:"float";s:4:"size";s:3:"big";s:8:"not null";b:1;}s:9:"longitude";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:5:"float";s:4:"size";s:3:"big";s:8:"not null";b:1;}}
```

I currently have two Services configured. One is drupalgap and the other is my own custom for specialized queries and API needs. I've tried enabling / disabling a variety of resources in both my Service endpoints. Both have session authentication enabled, use a REST server, return json formats, and include a variety of resources including all of those user `system`, `drupalgap_user`, and `user`.

What should i do about this missing 'services_user' table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That table was added in Services 7.x-3.10; it sounds like one of three things has happened:

1. You've updated the module but not run the database updates. If you have drush run `drush updb`, or visit /update.php to go through the process.
2. You've already run the updates but something went wrong
3. The table was removed accidentally (maybe by a backup restore)

In either of the last two cases, you can install the table manually with:

```
$schema = drupal_get_schema_unprocessed('services');         
db_create_table('services_user', $schema['services_user']);
```

or

```
module_load_include('install', 'services');
services_update_7402();
```